# I get error Unable to cast object of type when try to loop within repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webforms, repeater

I working on asp.net web forms. I face issue when try to get value of checkbox column inside repeater control.

I get error

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater'.'
```

error happen when loop within repeater control `foreach (Repeater gvr in repPSStatus.Items)`

what I do within code is :

1- click on print button to update status column on database based on id if checkbox checked

2- then after that will loop within repeater control to get checkbox value have checked true

3-get id from repeater and update on database column status with true when checkbox checked
is true .

what I try as below :

```
  protected void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (Repeater gvr in repPSStatus.Items)
        {

            if (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked == true)
            {
                string Id = gvr.Items[5].ToString();
  
                string msg = busiObj.updatestatus(Id);
                if (msg == "SUCCESS")
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

and on reprint.aspx page

```
 <table class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>StatusCheck</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repPSStatus">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td><%# Eval("id") %></td>
    <td class="GridCentre" style="width:20px;">  <asp:CheckBox id="chkSel" runat="server" Checked=false/> </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**updated post**

from code how to get id value on foreach loop under print click button

on line `string Id = gvr.Items[id].ToString();`

```
protected void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (RepeaterItem gvr in repPSStatus.Items)
            {

                if (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked == true)
                {
                    string Id = gvr.Items[id].ToString();
      
                    string msg = busiObj.updatestatus(Id);
                    if (msg == "SUCCESS")
                    {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try `foreach (RepeaterItem gvr in repPSStatus.Items)` or `foreach (var gvr in repPSStatus.Items)`

Comment: ok this is good but remaining one thing how to get id value on asp.net backend forms

Comment: i updated my post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your eval("id") does not have any kind of "tag" to find by, and worse yet, you don't have a runat="server" on that tag.

However, do you really need to display that "id" anyway?

I mean, you could dump/remove the id expression, and do it this way:

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" Checked="false"
       myid='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
```

Then code:

```
        foreach (RepeaterItem gvr in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox ckSel = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chksel");

            if (ckSel.Checked)
            {
                string id = ckSel.Attributes["myid"];

            }
        }
```

I mean, I suppose you could do this:

```
       <td id="mytdid" runat="server"><%# Eval("id") %></td>
```

and then do a find control on a HtmlGeneraicControl, and then use inner text. However, since you have to find/get/use/enjoy and go to all the trouble to get the check box control, then just "hang" into that checkbox a "made up" attribute that is the eval("id") expression, and thus get both values (checked, and id) in one shot.